# how to echo data from this string with php

Tags: php

I want to extract the items I wanted from the following string
**And I'm going to do this with PHP**
Can anyone help me with this?

my string :

```
    google.search.cse.api7456({
      "cursor": {
        "currentPageIndex": 0,
        "estimatedResultCount": "2570000000",
        "moreResultsUrl": "http://www.google.com/",
        "resultCount": "2,570,000,000",
        "searchResultTime": "0.36",
        "pages": [
          {
            "label": 1,
            "start": "0"
          },
          {
            "label": 2,
            "start": "20"
          },
          {
            "label": 3,
            "start": "40"
          },
          {
            "label": 4,
            "start": "60"
          },
          {
            "label": 5,
            "start": "80"
          }
        ]
      },
      "context": {
        "title": "Web Search",
        "total_results": "0"
      },
      "results": [
        {
          "cacheUrl": "http://www.google.com/search?q=cache:ZQh_B4K4VhQJ:www.php.net",
          "clicktrackUrl": "https://www.google.com/url?client=internal-element-cse&cx=partner-pub-9134522736300956:4140494421&q=https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.phar.php&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwitgb3goN3vAhXS8LsIHedyCqwQFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw18842X_9SqFEhhaIwQBHac",
          "content": "... Convert a phar \u003cb\u003earchive\u003c/b\u003e to a non-executable tar or zip file; Phar::\nconvertToExecutable — Convert a phar \u003cb\u003earchive\u003c/b\u003e to another executable phar \n\u003cb\u003earchive\u003c/b\u003e file format&nbsp;...",
          "contentNoFormatting": "... Convert a phar archive to a non-executable tar or zip file; Phar::\nconvertToExecutable — Convert a phar archive to another executable phar \narchive file format ...",
          "title": "Phar - Manual - PHP",
          "titleNoFormatting": "Phar - Manual - PHP",
          "formattedUrl": "https://www.\u003cb\u003ephp\u003c/b\u003e.net/manual/en/book.phar.\u003cb\u003ephp\u003c/b\u003e",
          "unescapedUrl": "https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.phar.php",
          "url": "https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.phar.php",
          "visibleUrl": "www.php.net",
          "richSnippet": {
            "metatags": {
              "viewport": "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
            }
          },
          "breadcrumbUrl": {
            "host": "www.php.net",
            "crumbs": [
              "manual",
              "book.phar.php"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "cacheUrl": "http://www.google.com/search?q=cache:oF_HUyG3J8MJ:en.wikipedia.org",
          "clicktrackUrl": "https://www.google.com/url?client=internal-element-cse&cx=partner-pub-9134522736300956:4140494421&q=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHAR_(file_format)&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwitgb3goN3vAhXS8LsIHedyCqwQFjABegQIExAB&usg=AOvVaw1B9f4N1kCv5G2jqhX6GEId",
          "content": "In software, a PHAR (\u003cb\u003ePHP Archive\u003c/b\u003e) file is a package format to enable distribution \nof applications and libraries by bundling many PHP code files and other&nbsp;...",
          "contentNoFormatting": "In software, a PHAR (PHP Archive) file is a package format to enable distribution \nof applications and libraries by bundling many PHP code files and other ...",
          "title": "PHAR (file format) - Wikipedia",
          "titleNoFormatting": "PHAR (file format) - Wikipedia",
          "formattedUrl": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHAR_(file_format)",
          "unescapedUrl": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHAR_(file_format)",
          "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHAR_(file_format)",
          "visibleUrl": "en.wikipedia.org",
          "richSnippet": {
            "metatags": {
              "referrer": "origin",
              "ogTitle": "PHAR (file format) - Wikipedia",
              "ogType": "website"
            }
          },
          "breadcrumbUrl": {
            "host": "en.wikipedia.org",
            "crumbs": [
              "wiki",
              "PHAR_(file_format)"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "cacheUrl": "http://www.google.com/search?q=cache:R7KjRoykITgJ:www.php.net",
          "clicktrackUrl": "https://www.google.com/url?client=internal-element-cse&cx=partner-pub-9134522736300956:4140494421&q=https://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.using.intro.php&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwitgb3goN3vAhXS8LsIHedyCqwQFjACegQIERAB&usg=AOvVaw15HS5ORidOHOyYH5D4cQyj",
          "content": "The phar stream wrapper allows accessing the files within a phar \u003cb\u003earchive\u003c/b\u003e using \n\u003cb\u003ePHP&#39;s\u003c/b\u003e standard file functions fopen(), opendir(), and others that work on regular&nbsp;...",
          "contentNoFormatting": "The phar stream wrapper allows accessing the files within a phar archive using \nPHP's standard file functions fopen(), opendir(), and others that work on regular ...",
          "title": "Using Phar Archives: Introduction - Manual - PHP",
          "titleNoFormatting": "Using Phar Archives: Introduction - Manual - PHP",
          "formattedUrl": "https://www.\u003cb\u003ephp\u003c/b\u003e.net/manual/en/phar.using.intro.\u003cb\u003ephp\u003c/b\u003e",
          "unescapedUrl": "https://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.using.intro.php",
          "url": "https://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.using.intro.php",
          "visibleUrl": "www.php.net",
          "richSnippet": {
            "metatags": {
              "viewport": "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
            }
          },
          "breadcrumbUrl": {
            "host": "www.php.net",
            "crumbs": [
              "manual",
              "phar.using.intro.php"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "cacheUrl": "http://www.google.com/search?q=cache:hdLqmA5_Q9IJ:medium.com",
          "clicktrackUrl": "https://www.google.com/url?client=internal-element-cse&cx=partner-pub-9134522736300956:4140494421&q=https://medium.com/%40tfidry/create-and-deploy-secure-phars-c5572f10b4dd&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwitgb3goN3vAhXS8LsIHedyCqwQFjAKegQIDBAC&usg=AOvVaw2pE_8uCbFfU5efIQFphwKt",
          "content": "29 Dec 2017 \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e For those who are not familiar with it, PHAR (\u003cb\u003ePhp Archive\u003c/b\u003e) is analogous to the \nJAR file concept but for PHP. It allows you to package an&nbsp;...",
          "contentNoFormatting": "29 Dec 2017 ... For those who are not familiar with it, PHAR (Php Archive) is analogous to the \nJAR file concept but for PHP. It allows you to package an ...",
          "title": "Create and deploy secure PHARs. For those who are not familiar ...",
          "titleNoFormatting": "Create and deploy secure PHARs. For those who are not familiar ...",
          "formattedUrl": "https://medium.com/@tfidry/create-and-deploy-secure-phars-c5572f10b4dd",
          "unescapedUrl": "https://medium.com/@tfidry/create-and-deploy-secure-phars-c5572f10b4dd",
          "url": "https://medium.com/%40tfidry/create-and-deploy-secure-phars-c5572f10b4dd",
          "visibleUrl": "medium.com",
          "richSnippet": {
            "cseImage": {
              "src": "https://miro.medium.com/max/414/1*hhQG6DX59IjMIhyPCmCT4w.png",
              "width": "229",
              "type": "1",
              "height": "220"
            },
            "metatags": {
              "twitterAppUrlIphone": "medium://p/c5572f10b4dd",
              "twitterTitle": "Create and deploy secure PHARs",
              "ogTitle": "Create and deploy secure PHARs",
              "alAndroidPackage": "com.medium.reader",
              "title": "Create and deploy secure PHARs. For those who are not familiar with it… | by Théo Fidry | Medium",
              "twitterLabel1": "Reading time",
              "ogType": "article",
              "twitterCard": "summary_large_image",
              "twitterData1": "8 min read",
              "alAndroidAppName": "Medium",
              "ogSiteName": "Medium",
              "twitterAppNameIphone": "Medium",
              "twitterSite": "@Medium",
              "alWebUrl": "https://medium.com/@tfidry/create-and-deploy-secure-phars-c5572f10b4dd",
              "articlePublishedTime": "2018-05-31T12:58:30.871Z",
              "parselyPostId": "c5572f10b4dd",
              "author": "Théo Fidry",
              "alIosAppStoreId": "828256236",
              "ogDescription": "For those who are not familiar with it, PHAR (Php Archive) is analogous to the JAR file concept but for PHP. It allows you to package an…",
              "ogImage": "https://miro.medium.com/max/414/1*hhQG6DX59IjMIhyPCmCT4w.png",
              "twitterImageSrc": "https://miro.medium.com/max/414/1*hhQG6DX59IjMIhyPCmCT4w.png",
              "referrer": "unsafe-url",
              "viewport": "width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1",
              "themeColor": "#000000",
              "twitterDescription": "For those who are not familiar with it, PHAR (Php Archive) is analogous to the JAR file concept but for PHP. It allows you to package an…",
              "alIosAppName": "Medium",
              "alIosUrl": "medium://p/c5572f10b4dd",
              "ogUrl": "https://medium.com/@tfidry/create-and-deploy-secure-phars-c5572f10b4dd",
              "twitterAppIdIphone": "828256236",
              "fbAppId": "542599432471018",
              "alAndroidUrl": "medium://p/c5572f10b4dd",
              "articleAuthor": "https://medium.com/@tfidry"
            }
          },
          "breadcrumbUrl": {
            "host": "medium.com",
            "crumbs": [
              "..."
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "cacheUrl": "http://www.google.com/search?q=cache:ANsd0gn_CG8J:matomo.org",
          "clicktrackUrl": "https://www.google.com/url?client=internal-element-cse&cx=partner-pub-9134522736300956:4140494421&q=https://matomo.org/docs/setup-auto-archiving/&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwitgb3goN3vAhXS8LsIHedyCqwQFjATegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw0nBYqpGgl4e-rA7nyxCCRr",
          "content": "You can execute the command “which \u003cb\u003ephp\u003c/b\u003e” or “which \u003cb\u003ephp\u003c/b\u003e” in a linux shell, to find \nout the the path of your \u003cb\u003ePHP\u003c/b\u003e&nbsp;...",
          "contentNoFormatting": "You can execute the command “which php” or “which php” in a linux shell, to find \nout the the path of your PHP ...",
          "title": "How to Set up Auto-\u003cb\u003eArchiving\u003c/b\u003e of Your Reports User Guide - Analytics ...",
          "titleNoFormatting": "How to Set up Auto-Archiving of Your Reports User Guide - Analytics ...",
          "formattedUrl": "https://matomo.org/docs/setup-auto-\u003cb\u003earchiving\u003c/b\u003e/",
          "unescapedUrl": "https://matomo.org/docs/setup-auto-archiving/",
          "url": "https://matomo.org/docs/setup-auto-archiving/",
          "visibleUrl": "matomo.org",
          "richSnippet": {
            "cseImage": {
              "src": "https://static.matomo.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/feature.png",
              "width": "321",
              "type": "1",
              "height": "157"
            },
            "metatags": {
              "twitterSite": "@matomo_org",
              "ogImageWidth": "1024",
              "ogTitle": "How to Set up Auto-Archiving of Your Reports - Analytics Platform - Matomo",
              "twitterLabel1": "Est. reading time",
              "ogLocale": "en_US",
              "ogImage": "https://static.matomo.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/feature.png",
              "ogType": "article",
              "articlePublisher": "https://www.facebook.com/Matomo.org",
              "twitterCard": "summary",
              "msapplicationTileimage": "https://static.matomo.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/cropped-DefaultIcon-270x270.png",
              "ogImageHeight": "500",
              "twitterData1": "14 minutes",
              "viewport": "width=device-width, initial-scale=1",
              "ogUrl": "https://matomo.org/docs/setup-auto-archiving/",
              "ogSiteName": "Analytics Platform - Matomo",
              "articleModifiedTime": "2021-03-24T02:22:11+00:00"
            }
          },
          "breadcrumbUrl": {
            "host": "matomo.org",
            "crumbs": [
              "User guides",
              "Configuration"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "findMoreOnGoogle": {
        "url": "https://www.sc.com/"
      }
    });
```

Comment: That looks like it should be a JSON String, although you may have missed a bit as it looks slightly invalid

Comment: You want to parse JSON. Take a look at this link https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php. Start by trying to echo one small portion such as: 
`"cursor": {"currentPageIndex": 0 }` so it prints 0